# Why isn't Typescript requiring my function to return a certain type?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a generic `Factory` function that should return a specific type:

```
type Factory<T> = () => T;

interface Widget {
  creationTime: number;
}

const build: Factory<Widget> = () => {
  return {
    creationTime: Date.now(),
    foo: 'bar',
  };
};
```

I would expect Typescript to throw an error because `foo` is not a property on the interface Widget. However, it does not.

But if I modify the `widgetFactory` function to the below code -- the only difference being that I explicitly declare the return type -- then it does throw an error:

```
const build: Factory<Widget> = (): Widget => {
  return {
    creationTime: Date.now(),
    foo: 'bar',
  };
};
```

Is there a way to make Typescript assign the same "strictness" to my generic `Factory` type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Object types in TypeScript do not in general prohibit extra properties.  They are "open" or "extendible", as opposed to "closed" or "exact" (see [microsoft/TypeScript#12936](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936)).  Otherwise it would be impossible to use subclasses or interface extensions:

```
interface FooWidget extends Widget {
   foo: string;
}
const f: FooWidget = { creationTime: 123, foo: "baz" };
const w: Widget = f; // okay
```

Sometimes people want such "exact" types, but they're not really part of the language.  Instead, what TypeScript has is [excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks), which only happens in very particular circumstances: when a "fresh" object literal is given a type that doesn't know about some of the properties in the object literal:

```
const x: Widget = { creationTime: 123, foo: "baz" }; // error, what's foo
```

An object literal is "fresh" if it hasn't been assigned to any type yet. The only difference between `x` and `w` is that in `x` the literal is "fresh" and excess properties are forbidden, while in `w` the literal is... uh... "stale" because it has already been given the type `FooWidget`.

---

From that it might seem that your `widgetFactory` should give an error, since you are returning the object literal without assigning it anywhere.  Unfortunately, freshness is lost in this case.  There's a longstanding issue, [microsoft/TypeScript#12632](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12632), that notes this, and depends on a very old issue, [microsoft/TypeScript#241](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/241). TypeScript automatically widens the returned type when checking to see if it's compatible with the expected return type...  and freshness is lost.  It looks like nobody likes this, but [it's hard to fix it without breaking other things](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12632#issuecomment-375739017).  So for now, it is what it is.

---

You already have one workaround: explicitly annotate the function's return type.  This isn't particularly satisfying, but it gets the job done.

```
export const WidgetFactory1: Factory<Widget> = {
   build: (): Widget => {
      return {
         creationTime: Date.now(),
         foo: 'bar', // error!
      };
   },
};
```

Other workarounds involving trying to force the compiler to compute exact types are possible but significantly uglier than what you're doing:

```
const exactWidgetFactory =
   <W extends Widget & Record<Exclude<keyof W, keyof Widget>, never>>(
      w: Factory<W>) => w;

export const WidgetFactory2 = exactWidgetFactory({
   build: () => { // error!
// ~~~~~ <-- types of property foo are incompatible
      return {
         creationTime: Date.now(),
         foo: 'bar',
      };
   },
});
```

So I'd suggest just continuing with what you've got there.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgMRxmgE8AeAFQD44BvAWACg4WBtAa2BIC44BnGFGQBzALq8AFAEo4AXhoUA3EwC+TJqEixEKNFlxwA6ggAmw4PAbMW2KMEwwEEJBQQBbYLyQBXNwCM0ZUY1Rg1waHhsZwEjU3MYQmxiKB4CIlIyYzMLGlk6JhY4P28EABsTSRl5fOtCuDsYbygkGrq223tHZ1cPXgARB2AAOiQIAHdpABoCtsL0CAheAHI-TCgl6drClUU4GbgVTZ31RmRUDBw8fAWs+LhQVCQTPljsy335xf5BESCQqKQMXQvGuEFuFjkdDgHQcThc7k8cAAjAAmADMkzgn14ACJVgAvHEHIIAmJjXjg+B5dC7AD0tLgEHYmBIJ1J8BAFLiELytGhdlh3QRvFRGKxC1xBKJOzg9PuUCg0ExYwAFg4li9PidNBFodF4JTEskSEiQekUpluTBcq0WMUyhU4NIuW85DQrLMGk0Wh7ZjYBV14b04ANUCNxlN9rNsXAVmsNrKGWhFVAAIRRljHWqHVRBNn6+4gIiG80kOT7TKFx7PV53ABkcAASsAolATGQAKIgbClbwmYBkTgkCDoIyYocj2s5TFIYAANzQVCoEgzcHJaSSGUMVCqNDGecYOu07KnCVLKMhoGLVqNpAkvqKJXKlTdULlyeg6cYcoAfn+-3AZAALRAXAMAkGAwAvJOYCKpBsBlp8cBrHgyBRG4YCwn4pTAKuXrNLafowoGPSIqGwyjBMUibH6LAxnG6w0W0WbbEcUgHkAA)