# typescript infer raw object type after index signature

Tags: typescript, type-inference

Let's say I have the object:

```
const styles = { product: { color: 'blue' } };
```

and with that the object type is inferred and I can access `foo.bar.baz` without a problem.

However, if I wanted type checking, I would need something like:

```
import type CSS from 'csstype';
type StyleSheet = Record<string,CSS.Properties>;

const styles:StyleSheet = {
    product: { color: 'blue' }
};
```

And the above would be valid, however, when accessing `styles` I would get `styles.whatever.color` or `styles.product.margin` as defined, which is undesired.

With that in mind, is there any way in Typescript to infer the original type of the object after it has been typed, so I can access its real properties, like so:

```
const styles:StyleSheet = { product: { color: 'blue' } }; // typed as 'StyleSheet' so I get type-checking
styles.whatever.margin // TS thinks this is valid because of the index signature;

const original = styles as OriginalObject; // infer original type so only real properties are accessible
original.whatever // invalid (expected)
original.product.color // valid

export default original;
```

### Update

replying @jcalx's:

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=41&pc=32#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBDAnmApnAZhCGoRHAcgGMBnEpVAgWAChaK0BhAZWbgF4MsA6ABV1SxgKEgG5a9ZGl4AlAPK8APABUANHABCAPg604+uAG89B0wG0A0nGAA7OAFEAHjCgBDIjEUBrFIgjo4NTgfPwDtAF0ALhNTfQ1LcLgYuABfZIAyJJpTY2zY-UtrOyciABsAVwATFG9ff0D1EPqI6Lz85QS4FGcUG0qSOAgAIwArFA84AH44WQUVBNVtOEi4GxQANxQoZJTxOhoGTQBBZnsVdSXOQ0LbYLqA5SiZ+SUOi3DFrV2JGiIIG3IcFcJGYSFKKGYAAsUCh4JwVF0en0BhoTmc1CxmFotAAKGCRZQASgJHB0MD2tD+APg5EQ4IGnGBoLpEOhsJxuVMmAgK05+TgQ1cUBWAEZVMlTH9StAVgQoChKtQ2qlxcqwLhKuUPLyJQZBcLCCKCKr+QhujAjqVgABzGyyoi9GBbY26-RSmWEeWKk38yEQTYGvmm-T62VGn3Bs3OS02u2EB02J1QJWmtLKtMpQkU-a0+ncADukNcToD3BAQuttj2uZEBaLJa21bBtfVEE1Hm47qgTZZJG4rfbMG4ftL+p7eYHWqHI623Cd0atttEQA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to check that `styles` is a `StyleSheet` without *widening* `styles` to `StyleSheet` and having the compiler forget about its individual properties.

---

One way to do this is just let the compiler infer the type for `styles` and trust TypeScript's structural type system to complain if you use it somewhere it doesn't like.  That is, assuming you have some function that requires a `StyleSheet`:

```
function someFunctionThatNeedsAStyleSheet(s: StyleSheet) { }
```

You can just make some unannotated objects:

```
const styles = { product: { color: 'gray' } };
const badStyles = { product: { colour: 'grey' } };
```

The compiler will remember their properties:

```
styles.whatever.margin // error;
styles.product.color // okay
```

And later, when you pass them to the function, it will either accept it or warn you:

```
someFunctionThatNeedsAStyleSheet(styles); // okay
someFunctionThatNeedsAStyleSheet(badStyles); // error!
// ----------------------------> ~~~~~~~~~
// Type '{ colour: string; }' has no properties in common 
// with type 'Properties<string | 0>'
```

You *do* get type checking here.  But of course, it's not in the same place where you declare the `styles` variable.

---

If you want to catch a bad `StyleSheet` right when you create it, you can use the above type-checking-function idea by making a helper function like this:

```
const asStyleSheet = <T extends StyleSheet>(t: T) => t;
```

The function `asStyleSheet()` is a generic identity function: it returns its input, with the same type as the input.  But the generic type is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `StyleSheet`, so you'll get an error if you pass in a bad one.  Like this:

```
const styles = asStyleSheet({ product: { color: 'gray' } }); // okay
const badStyles = asStyleSheet({ product: { colour: 'grey' } }) // error!
// ---------------------------------------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// 'colour' does not exist in type 'Properties<string | 0>'. 
// Did you mean to write 'color' ?
```

By using `asStyleSheet()`, you are checking the type of `styles` without changing it; the output of `asStyleSheet()` is the same type as the input.  So the compiler remembers its properties:

```
styles.whatever.margin // error;
styles.product.color // okay
```

Looks good.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBDAnmApnAwgZU3AZlCEOAcgGMBncpVYgWACgGHq1MkAbFTACxRXgC8cAEopS0ACYAeKlGAA7AOYAaDNgB0ABQKpYwFOQB8Abib15AQxAGwF0mgBSAVyoB1C8HgBvM3D94neVIYYAh5OHJCFAAxQODQ+QAVbgsYADk+CXIAQTZETh4+GAAKcgAuODyC3n4ASjgvOABfX39xeSoIjgM4IUawAgknYIrG8XZoCuJFKAtEYmbm03p-OHbOgCMLCSqevrgBiCGRhrWICacoKZmUecWm5YZVqnyDdQB3FJgUADcUKHUIAsUEUCjgAHpwXB-gQoMtnt1yOpDscYOpxtAIVCIABrOZmJ7+SLWWJBEJhZKpDIoLK5bqFfilRG1eFEqKk+IUr7U2m7BklLY7ZnGLHQqCwgCEhL8kLgAFoFYqlcqVarDHAAH5a7Xa6WixLINDEMbnCCXCqyBSKEVNBYpchweQQA46f4hHpg8QgEBhOB62XvTzcBCGkjaCC6d3kGQwORKOAAHzgAAZDAszC1GFnLNZyLZ7HAABIodi6Bp69bwCzkPk1QRwKSJaEAD2+8iylXpdcMxRgFUS9QE6pgjxWbTCnRenAdQmrtaKxX6g2GfdOGKuJBmcwWTWaLIrE-ggt2M7gc67C6XRxXozOFw30ygtx3e9FMOgUrHMqhqt-f--yrqjqwHAf6UJkKalwLBIEA9E68AoM2wCdGCLBhq6egGDGcaKImKZpuofpfqKAAiwASHAiBmnA1gWOEMDOu8cjfCQ64LAA-ERepTm8nypL8-yAsCoLhLK75wtxiIfF8AlQG+4rQJJrxIiiK7oqacmyri+L0E0QA)

Comment: Thanks so much! That's great. There's only one thing, though: On the second example, why `const styles = asStyleSheet({ product: { color: 'gray', foo:'bar' } })` doesn't show any error as `foo` is not a property os CSS.Properties while `const s:StyleSheet = {product:{color: 'gray', foo: 'bar'}};` is invalid as expected?

Comment: Hey @jcalz, your response here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61811167/165750 guided me to produce this (Playground link to code updated on the questions as it's too long for a comment). Let me know if you believe that's a good way of implementing it? Thanks for your answers around SO.